# Moving VMWare Fusion image to Boot Camp

Tags: windows-7, vmware-fusion, boot-camp

I have Windows 7 64-bit running in VMWare Fusion on my MacBook, but am disappointed with the performance, and so I want to try Boot Camp. However, I'd like to avoid reinstalling Windows and all my applications; I just want to somehow copy my VMWare Fusion "disk image" to a Boot Camp partition.

My initial thoughts are that I should be able to run a Windows backup program in VMWare Fusion to back up the entire virtual disk, then set up Boot Camp and restore from that backup.  However, Googling finds a few posts by people who have tried that and have encountered problems.

So, is there a "known good" procedure for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would indeed have to create a exact mirror using any program capable of doing that, Norton Ghost. And then write back that exact mirror to the Boot Camp partition. But a better bet is to do a reinstall as you will encounter other problems due to hardware configurations that differ too much...